# setHeaderView() for submenu is not working in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Am working on menus and submenus. I have added setHeaderView() for my submenu and it doesn seem to work. Code is as follows :

```
View dialogTitle = inflater.inflate(R.layout.demo, null);
((TextView)dialogTitle.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title_text)).setText("Add to playlist:");
item.getSubMenu().setHeaderView(vgDialogTitle);
```

And xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_title_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me out!

Comment: did you get any solution?